# loop elements by data attribute and replace values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to loop through all elements that contain a certain data attribute and then replace/remove certain characters.

```
//replace chars put in by money mask since model is double
$("input[data-input-mask='money']").each(function() {
        alert(this.value); // shows: $ 1,000
        alert('test$ ,'.replace('$ ', '').replace(',', '')); //shows: test
        this.value = this.value.replace('$ ', '').replace(',', '');
        alert(this.value); //shows: $ 1,000
});
```

this.value is still the original value. What might I be doing wrong here?

Comment: May be original value does not have `$` and `,`.. Try `'Hey$,'.replace('$','').replace(',','');`

Comment: Can you post example html for an input you are trying get with that selector?

Comment: Your code [works](https://jsfiddle.net/51pxs5cg/). Please show some more context. Have you simplified your code in this question?

Comment: It's working well. https://jsfiddle.net/3esrgyzn/

Comment: There is no `$ `(consider space) sub-string in your string..

Comment: Sorry I figured out the issue. It was being removed but the input masking was still bound and just adding it back in. I had to unbind the masking before submitting and now it works. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That's why we asked for more context, HTML and such.

Comment: Ya was being caused by another script which I didn't think about when I asked the question.

Comment: @Tsukasa take a look at my answer, it's way easier to do it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.localeString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

### UPDATE

After rereading the OP, I realize the opposite is desired. That's still easy. Instead of using a mask, use `localString()`. Then it's a matter of not using `localestring()` when you processing the values.

### SNIPPET

```js
$("input[data-input-mask='money']").each(function() {
    var cash = parseFloat(this.value);
    var green = cash.toLocaleString('en-EN', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' });
    alert(green);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input data-input-mask='money' value="623.23">
<input data-input-mask='money' value="20199">
<input data-input-mask='money' value="">
```

Comment: I like this but the masking that I was adding, I needed to strip out the formatting and only have a numeric value before it was submitted to the controller which I did by unbinding the mask to the input. However this solved the next issue I was looking to figure out when I wanted to display the value outside of an input field that added the symbols back in.

Comment: That's great, I'm glad that you resolved your issue and got a bonus. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each element and replace it like this.

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
            //Retrieve all text of amount di;
            $.each( $('.amount'), function(){
                var unique_id = $(this).text();
   //check if any price is match to FREE THEN replace it with   NOT FREE
                 if(unique_id=='FREE'){
                        $(this).text("NOT FREE");
                 }
            });
    });
    </script>
```